# Uncertainty due to counting statistics in binned data

Tags: statistics, error-propagation

I am interested in calculating the uncertainty due to counting statistics such that I can obtain vertical error bars for a histogram.

I have a probability density function that tells me the probability of a count at $t>0$.  The pdf is not normal; it is the sum of two decaying exponentials.  The domain of the pdf is $0$ to $\infty$; however, the data is binned between $0$ and some $t_\text{max}$.  How do I use the pdf to calculate the standard deviation in the number of counts for each bin?

Comment: My current idea is to, using the equations for continuous random variables, calculate the mean for each bin and then use that to calculate the standard deviation.  In this case, do I need to normalize the pdf for each bin, or just for the total interval [0, $t_\text{max}$]?

Comment: The sum of two independent exponential random variables with rate $\lambda = 1/\mu$ has a gamma distribution with shape parameter $2$ and rate parameter $\lambda.$ That might be a start--if we knew the exponentials are independent and of the same rate. Is that either explicitly stated? Or a reasonable assumption?

Comment: Thanks for your comment!  The form of the pdf is $p(t) = Ae^{Bt} + Ce^{DT}$, so it is not the sum of two independent random variables.  One random variable is described by the sum of two exponentials.